# Bash Ubuntu on Windows 10, connect to host port 22: Connection Failure

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I just installed the Bash Ubuntu on Windows 10 natively. When I try and acess a remote server I get ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection refused

I have tried to find a solutions, but the solutions doesn't work.

This is what I have tried:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user/733120#733120

When I could not acess `/etx/hosts` I tried this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/326239/cannot-access-etc-hosts

After downloading `gksudo` to try and edit `/etc/hosts` I got this error message `(gksudo:2601): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su]. Also, "Connection refused" is a specific error with a specific cause, and you should be able to find existing questions about that specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure everything is correctly setup?

I just tried 
`ssh -T git@github.com`
in my Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

and it totally works Returning

```
Hi <usernamer>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Maybe you have some settings that prevent connections? for example in ~/.bashrc?

Maybe your server needs a different port? use `ssh -p 2222` for that.